# Regex replace text in python

Tags: python

I have text looks like:

```
Added "a-foo-b" foo.
```

The goal is to use a **regular expression** to replace the second foo to bar, and leave the first foo between two double quotes untouched.
So in the text above, the result I am looking for is:

```
Added "a-foo-b" bar.
```

Thanks

Comment: re.sub(r'foo', 'bar', s)  # This will replace all foo to bar in text

Comment: Can you rely on the full stop terminator being there?

Answer (score 3):

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r'("[^"]+".*)foo')

s = '''Added "a-foo-b" foo.'''

s_new = re.sub(pat, r'\1bar', s)
print(s_new)
```

Since you said the goal is to leave the one in double quotes alone, I focused on the double quotes as the key.  The parentheses form a "match group" that saves the matched string; this match group matches the double-quotes and what is inside them, and then the pattern matches the second foo.  The replacement pattern will replace everything we matched, but that's okay because we use a `\1` to put back the match group part, and then we have `bar` to replace that second `foo`.

If you know there cannot be any more double-quotes after the `foo` you want to replace, this might be a better pattern:

```
pat = re.compile(r'(".*".*)foo')
```

This pattern matches a double-quote, then anything, then another double-quote.  The first pattern won't work if the quoted string includes an escaped double-quote, but this one would.  But if you use this pattern on this string:

```
s = '''Added "a-foo-b" foo.  "Wow, another foo"'''
```

The match group would match past the second foo and would match the third foo, even though it is in quotes.  This is because the pattern match is "greedy".

EDIT:

Question: Yeah, what if `s = '''Added "a-foo-b" foo.Deleted "a-foo-b".'''`

Answer: If the pattern always holds, you know there won't be an escaped double-quote inside the double-quotes, and you can use the first pattern.  Then you can apply multiple patterns to detect and/or replace whatever you want.  `pat_added` below solves the problem we wanted to solve before; it anchors on the `Added` part of the string so it won't do anything to the `Deleted` part of the string.  If you did want to match and replace part of the string inside the quotes, `pat_deleted` shows how to do it; it has three match groups, and puts back the first and last one to let you replace the middle one.  Actually we don't really need a match group for the middle one; we could leave the part we are replacing outside a match group, like we did with the first pattern.

```
import re
pat_added = re.compile(r'(Added\s+"[^"]+"\s+)\w+')
pat_deleted = re.compile(r'(Deleted\s+"[a-z]-)([^-]+)(-[a-z]"\.)')

s = '''Added "a-foo-b" foo.Deleted "a-foo-b".'''
s = re.sub(pat_added, r'\1bar', s)
s = re.sub(pat_deleted, r'\1bar\3', s)
print(s)
```

Comment: Not bad, but what if you want to skip all `foo`-s in quotes?

Comment: Yeah, what if s = '''Added "a-foo-b" foo.Deleted "a-foo-b".'''

Answer (score 0):

If your text always ends with a dot, you can try something like:

```
echo 'Added "a-foo-b" foo.'  | sed s/foo\.$/bar/g

Added "a-foo-b" bar
```

Comment: This is not python :-) and let the OP show some effort before posting an answer...

Comment: Ok, I just thought that see the regex will help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

An approach with string methods.

```
>>> s='Added "a-foo-b" foo test'
>>> needle='foo'
>>> rind=s.rfind('foo')
>>> if rind!=-1:
...  s=s[:rind] + needle + s[rind+len(needle):]
```