# Replacing things like \t\r using Python

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have a tab-delimited txt file.

I am trying to replace

```
\t\t
```

by

```
\t999999999\t
```

At first I tried using notepad++ to do it. I did it. But it was too slow.

So I am thinking of whether it will be fast if I use python for this.

I did some searching and found [Regex replace text in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258269/regex-replace-text-in-python)

but it seems that question is not about replacing things like \t per se, but simply using regex to replace normal words.

**My try that didn't work**

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.FileInput("input.txt",inplace=1):
    line = line.replace(r'\t\t',r'\t999999999\t')
    print line,
```

Comment: Look into Python's string `replace()` method: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm

Comment: @user you mean this http://regex101.com/r/vU4hH1/2 ?

Comment: If you're trying to replace a literal tab character in the input and not the two characters `\ ` and `t`, you do not want a raw string `r'\t'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your needs, you can use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)..

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\t)(?=\t)', '999999999', 'foo\tbar\t\tbaz')
'foo\tbar\t999999999\tbaz'
```

Or the [`replace()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm) method to do this:

```
>>> s = 'foo\tbar\t\tbaz'
>>> s.replace('\t\t', '\t999999999\t')
'foo\tbar\t999999999\tbaz'
```

### Edit

```
>>> import fileinput
>>> for line in fileinput.input('input.txt', inplace = 1):
...     print line.replace('\t\t', '\t999999999\t'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Per @skram's comment, have you tried:

```
myText = r'\t\r'

newText = myText.replace(r'\t\r', r'\t9999\r')
```

which returns

```
\t9999\r
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this is the way to go. But as I tried to apply your code to my situation but it didn't work. Perhaps I did something wrong in the process. I edited my question to add what I have tried.